# Git: having problems trying to keep a clean history tree

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have here a git repository with a few people working on it.
I've set up `branch.master.rebase = true` and `branch.master.mergeoptions = --no-ff`, but I have came across a problem:

Someone tried to merge a feature branch into master. The merge was successful, and git said the branch was 30 commits ahead of origin/master. When he tried to push the changes, git rejected the push because there where changes in the remote, so he had to git pull. When he did the pull, git made a rebase for the commits that where merged into master, and now it was only 29 commits ahead of master.

I believe the merge commit was lost, because after the rebase, the commits where reapplied as new commits, and not commits that came from the feature branch.

After the push, the tree was like that:

```
* c3'(head, master, origin/master)
* c2'
* c1'
|  * c3 (feature_branch, origin/feature_branch)
|  * c2
|  * c1
| /
*
```

That is what I was trying to achieve:

```
* c4 (head, master, feature_branch, origin/master)
| \
|  * c3 (origin/feature_branch)
|  * c2
|  * c1
| /
*
```

The merge looked like a fast-forwarding merge, what I'm trying to avoid, to keep branching history.

Any tips on what I can do to avoid this?

Thanks,

Edit:
This article descibes my problem:
http://notes.envato.com/developers/rebasing-merge-commits-in-git/

Now I'm aware of the --preserve-merges option for `git rebase`, but is there a way to make this option default?

Otherwise, the developers would have to `git fetch` and `git rebase origin/master` instead of just `git pull`.

Comment: Try this link: http://www.randyfay.com/node/89 Helped me the most.

Comment: Luckly the devs here don't know about `git push --force`..

But I'm not sure how this article would help, could you please explain more?

We push feature_branches to the remote, because every work gets reviewed before being merged into master, so we can't rebase the branch right before merging (tho the devs are instructed to rebase from master before pushing the branch the first time).

Comment: Personally, I like the pull request strategy mentioned under "Alternatives to the Merge Workflow". You could use http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/ for this review process. The one person that is responsible for the merging with the master branch should be restrictive and reject the pull requests if they are not mergeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you use branch.master.rebase = true if you want to save all branching history?

Comment: I wasn't aware that I would lose merge commits with `--rebase`.

Comment: "If the upstream branch already contains a change you have made (e.g., because you mailed a patch which was applied upstream), then that commit will be skipped." Merge commit represents the changes which is already contained in previous commits. So it will be skipped.

Comment: I also set that option to avoid merging branches, I wanted to keep only feature branches ins history.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping history clean is over-emphasized a lot of times. The nature of the DAG (directed acyclic graph) allows easy set manipulation of references to particular commits (sha1s, tags, branches, tree-ish, etc) to see what commits were merged already or which ones still need to be. Not rebasing preserves history in a more accurate manner which shows what got developed in parallel and when those efforts were merged.

To add, you can be fairly organized anyway by using branch-per-feature if you can make your features small. This is the workflow we use:

https://plus.google.com/109096274754593704906/posts/R4qkeyRadLR

Initially I liked keeping my history nice and tidy and linear. As I used Git more and more, it became apparent that this was a carry over from using non-DVCS tools like SVN.

Comment: We create branch-for-feature. By keeping history clean, I mean avoinding merging branches, so the commit tree is simple to understand.

Comment: Depends if you are talking about merges within the feature or merges to integrate the feature.